# How to createView from mongodb to make Array to String?

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, aggregation-framework

mongodb has a createView api, which can create a view like a real table and change with the original table.

but I dont found that a pipeline method to switch the whole object array to string.

such as
origin collection

| A header | This is array |
| --- | --- |
| First | Array<Object> |
| Second | Array<Object> |

to a view

| A header | This is array to string |
| --- | --- |
| First | '[{...},{...}]' |
| Second | '[{...},{...}]' |

How to make this example works?

Comment: Can you please provide input data and desired result as JSON text.

Answer (score 1):

There are no operators to transform array to string. You will have to use javascript. Good news is Mongo supports javascript using [$function](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v5.0/reference/operator/aggregation/function/). To use
`$function`, you must have server-side scripting enabled (default).

Your pipeline should look something like this.

```
[
    {
        $project: {
            "item":{
                $function: {
                    body: function(item) {
                        return JSON.stringify(item)
                    },
                    args: ["$item"],
                    lang: "js"
               }
            }
        }
    }
]
```